# Executing php script with Cyrillic gives internal 500 error

Tags: php, xml

With a few words, I would like to add an additional node to my existing XML Structure (using SimpleXMLElement) with Cyrillic word. For example:

```
$mainnode->addChild('topic','Город');
```

I tried several tricks and functions like iconv etc, but each time I try to execute the script in the server it returns the

> Internal 500 Server Error

message, if I delete that line, it executes just fine.

Comment: I read you have found the culprit, but can you check the error log of your webserver that should have more information *why* technically the 500 internal server error was triggered. That would be interesting to know in the light of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just for everyone experiencing similar issue, i guess it could happen with all type of scripts, like Arabic,Chinese etc.

it turned out that the

```
default_charset
```

in my php.ini file was left empty so after putting

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

now it works fine

Comment: which PHP verssion are you on? IN PHP 5.6 It defaults to utf-8, it sounds like you are on pre 5.6 versions - please update as it doesn't recieve any support from php.net - http://php.net/supported-versions.php since it is EOL